# How to fetch documents with multiple revisions in CouchDB?

Tags: couchdb

Is there a way to retrieve only documents from CouchDB where the number of revisions matches a certain criteria (e.g. > 1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build a map/reduce view keyed on the `_rev` field. This field is *currently* an integer of the revision count, plus a checksum of the contents: `297-0d7aa4331b85426b4ce3bbaa2131280f`.

### This is subject to change at any time

The revision format has changed before and could change again. So to use this field is a little risky. However, I've used it myself I emitted a key of the checksum part, to have a view of all documents, shuffled.